# How to perform a DELETE request using RestKit (0.20)?

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to send a DELETE request using RestKit, but it seems that it is always sent as "GET". Here is my code:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor
                                       responseDescriptorWithMapping:[self objectMapping]
                                       method:RKRequestMethodDELETE
                                       pathPattern:nil
                                       keyPath:nil
statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];


RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];
[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    [delegate onRequestSuccess:mappingResult.array];

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"operation failed with error: %@", error);
    [delegate onRequestError:operation message:error];
}];

[objectRequestOperation start];
```

I tried also using RKObjectManager:deleteObject, which does correctly send a DELETE request, but the response does not get mapped.

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:request.url];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
[manager deleteObject:nil path:request.urlString parameters:nil
              success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                  Tag *tag = mappingResult.firstObject; // this is null, does not get mapped

              } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error) {
                  RKLogError(@"Error deleting tag %@, error: %@", tagId, error);
              }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `RKObjectRequestOperation` you need to configure the `request` yourself. It's GET because that is the default.

If you use `RKObjectManager` then you can use `deleteObject` instead which will do it for you.

Comment: How do you set it for RKObjectRequestOperation? I have it set in the RKResponseDescriptor, but that doesn't have any effect.

Comment: `    [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];  `. The delete you're setting is just telling RestKit about the response to a request.